# How to limit number of parallel file copy using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

As per gsutil cp command documentation -

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp

we can use `gsutil -m` option for parallel multi-threaded/multi-processing file copy.

Since we are using gsutil inside a docker container and the POD size is very small which will not be helpful if more that 5 files are getting copied in parallel.

Is there any way we can limit the number of files to be copied in parallel using gsutil -m option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gsutil performs the specified operation using a combination of
> multi-threading and multi-processing. The number of threads and
> processors are determined by **parallel_thread_count** and
> **parallel_process_count**, respectively. These values are set in the
> **.boto** configuration file or specified in individual requests with the
> **-o** top-level flag.

[Boto configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil)